# Change formatting of specific numbered list item in MS Word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-office-2016, typing

In a numbered list in MS Word, how can I customize style just for one number? Like this:

1. List item
2. List item <= other color, other size
3. List item
4. List item

Note:
What I do not mean, is changing style for text. I want customize style for menu number, itself.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to define a character style (not a paragraph style) that has the style changes that you want for the numbering. Then, select the paragraph mark at the end of the appropriate list paragraph, and apply the style to it. Or, if you just need one number changed in the whole document, select the paragraph mark, and manually apply the style changes to it. Either way, you end up with something like this.

[image: List with a large hot pink number for one item]

To clear the style from an item, select the paragraph mark, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (or click **Clear All** in the **Styles** pane or **Clear All Formatting** on the **Home** tab), as usual.